# Azure devops - use runtime variables in template

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a pipeline that compares a feature branch to the latest common master.
The user provides a `feature_hash` which is then used to determine the common merge-base with the master branch (`git_merge_base.merge_base`).

For each - the feature and the master branch - I then proceed to check whether the binaries have already been built, and if not built & upload them.

My problem is that I can't seem to pass this "runtime decision" about the `merge-base` down to the template scope and have the variable evaluated at runtime.

I have read through the documentation but this left me more confused than before.

It looks somewhat like this:

```
stages:
  - stage: determine_merge_base
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
    - template: ../job_templates/determine_merge_base.yml
      parameters:
        ref: ${{ parameters.feature_hash }}

  - stage: build_master
    dependsOn: determine_merge_base
    jobs:
    - template: ../job_templates/check_if_binary_release_exists.yml
      parameters:
          ref: "$[stageDependencies.determine_merge_base.DetermineMergeBase.outputs['git_merge_base.merge_base']]"
    - template: ../job_templates/build_and_upload_binaries.yml
      parameters:
          ref: "$[stageDependencies.determine_merge_base.DetermineMergeBase.outputs['git_merge_base.merge_base']]"

  - stage: build_feature
    dependsOn: [] 
    jobs:
    - template: ../job_templates/check_if_binary_release_exists.yml
      parameters:
          ref: ${{ parameters.feature_hash }}
    - template: ../job_templates/build_and_upload_binaries.yml
      parameters:
          ref: ${{ parameters.feature_hash }}
```

The `ref` parameter gets passed through 3 layers of template to be finally used within a step template like this:

```
- script: |
      git_commit="${{parameters['ref']}}"
```

Where I end up with this error:

```
stageDependencies.determine_merge_base.DetermineMergeBase.outputs['git_merge_base.merge_base']: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".determine_merge_base.DetermineMergeBase.outputs['git_merge_base.merge_base']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the gist of it is you can't use parameters, as they are evaluated BEFORE runtime (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-template-parameter-as-part-of-a-condition)).

So, you can only use variables, which you did with `$[stageDepencies.<etc>]`, but you have to go all the way through, meaning **at the execution time of your step as well**.
You can use variables value for parameters, but only if the value of the variable is known "early enough" (ie pretty much when the whole pipeline starts), like `BuildNumber` and other similar ones, which is not your case.

So, in your case, I think this below is the way to do it. You can then package all that in your job templates, but the point is to use the variables directly in your templates, and NOT whatever you pass in as parameters. Typically, when I use parameters on my templates it is for default values, or for values known before the pipeline starts. Everything evaluated on-the-flight has to be consumed as variables  :

```
  - stage: MyCheckStage
    jobs:    
    - job: MyCheckJob
      steps:
      - script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CheckValue;isOutput=true]MyValue"
        name: MyCheckStep

  - stage: MyDecisionStage
    dependsOn: MyCheckStage
    variables:
      CheckValueFromPreviousStage: $[ stageDependencies.MyCheckStage.MyCheckJob.outputs['MyCheckStep.CheckValue'] ]
    jobs:   
    - job: myJob
      steps:
      - script: |
          echo $(CheckValueFromPreviousStage)
```